# Expanding arrays in object properties to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How am I able to convert the following object:

```
data = {
  sp: [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ],
  jh: [ '1', '0', 'AB' ],
  oa: [ 27493, 9837, 3781 ]
}
```

into the following array of objects:

```
new_data = [
  {sp: 'A', jh: '1', oa: 27493},
  {sp: 'B', jh: '0', oa: 9837},
  {sp: 'C', jh: 'AB', oa: 3781}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the arrays are all the same size, `map` one of them and `reduce` the keys using the current index.

```js
const data = {
  sp: [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ],
  jh: [ '1', '0', 'AB' ],
  oa: [ 27493, 9837, 3781 ]
};

let keys = Object.keys(data);
let new_data = data[keys[0]].map(( _, idx ) => keys.reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, [c]: data[c][idx] }), {}));

console.log(new_data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get all of the key-value pairs in the object.
2. You can take the length of the values of the array for the first entry as the length of the output, assuming that all of the arrays in the object are of the same length.
3. Then, you can map over all of the possible indexes and use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create an object with the keys from the original object and the value being the value at that index in the array for that key in the original object.

```js
const data = {
  sp: [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ],
  jh: [ '1', '0', 'AB' ],
  oa: [ 27493, 9837, 3781 ]
}
let entries = Object.entries(data);
let res = entries[0][1].map((_, i)=>Object.fromEntries(
                              entries.map(([k, v])=>[k, v[i]])));
console.log(res);
```